# Building xml messages from byte buffer

Tags: java, xml, state-machine

I have a function that is handed an array of bytes.  These bytes may contain a portion, a whole, or a whole and a portion of an xml message.  I have successfully used a state machine to try to parse the message until today when we realized that if a second source was sending us data, that i can get the first half of a message and immediately after the beginning of another message from the second source.  I'd like to be able to rectify that by discarding the message that was out of order.  I don't think i should store it and keep hold of it until complete.

Here is my state machine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    {
        byte data = bytes[i];

        //based on the read state, perform an action.  This is attempting to 
        //determine if we are reading the beginning of a message, or the end of the message.
        if (bufferIndex == BmsConstants.MAX_DRAWING_LENGTH)
        {
            resetState();               
        }

        switch (readState)
        {
            case SYNC:
                //we've read:  <
                if (data == '<')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_LT;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                } else
                {
                    resetState();
                }
                break;
            case START_LT:
                //we've read:  <?
                if (data == '?')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_QM;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                } else
                {
                    resetState();
                }
                break;
            case START_QM:
                //we've read:  <?x
                if (data == 'x')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                } else
                {
                    resetState();
                }
                break;
            case START_X:
                //we've read:  <, now just read until we get to the </event>
                if (data == '<')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_LT;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                else
                {
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
            case END_LT:
                //we've read:  </
                if (data == '/')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_SLASH;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                else
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
            case END_SLASH:
                //we've read:  </e
                if (data == 'e')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_E;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                else
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
            case END_E:
                //we've read:  </ev
                if (data == 'v')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_V;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                else
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
            case END_V:
                //we've read:  </eve
                if (data == 'e')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_E1;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                else
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
            case END_E1:
                //we've read:  </even
                if (data == 'n')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_N;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                else
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
            case END_N:
                //we've read:  </event
                if (data == 't')
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_T;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                else
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
            case END_T:
                //we've read:  </event>  
                //End of the message, now we can parse it.
                if (data == '>')
                {
                    //readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.END_GT;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;

                    parseXml(new String(buff, 0, bufferIndex));
                    resetState();
                }
                else
                {
                    readState = DrawingDeviceParserState.START_X;
                    buff[bufferIndex++] = (char) data;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

The weakness is this state machine lies within the case START_X.  I will continue to read until i find the  tag, which in the case of the 2 messages stuffed together out of order, will be at the end of the second message.
What i am hoping someone can do is either advise me that a state machine is not exactly what i should be looking to do, or modify my code/logic to better handle this fringe case.

Comment: Not sure what the specific issue is.

Comment: I added clarification of my issues.

Comment: i take it you are handling a very specific xml format?  you seem to be assuming a single byte encoding for the xml.

Comment: i don't see how you expect to be able to handle arbitrary jumbling of messages?  seems to me your problem is _before_ you get to the parsing.  i would avoid getting into the state where you have broken messages (if at all possible).

Comment: it's not that it is so specific, it is just that i don't know what is in the message.  I know that it is xml, but i don't know if it is a whole message or more than one message,etc. that is why i did the state machine to make sure i got the tags appropriately.  I don't feel like this is the best way, which is why i'm posting the question.

Comment: as for the jumbling portion, i am trying other ways of preventing nefarious xml messages from getting to the parsing code.

Comment: if you could get multi-byte xml, then this code isn't going to work at all.

Comment: @jtahlborn - the for loop at the top of the code segment loops through an array of bytes that is passed in. so it technically is multi-byte...

Comment: you need to read up on how characters are encoded into bytes.  if the xml is encoded using, for example, utf-16 then a "character" is made up of 2 bytes (and the byte order depends on the utf-16 variant).  like i said, this code does _not_ work with multi-byte char encodings in the xml.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were meaning by multi-byte.  The xml is, and always will be, UTF-8.